# using foil-backed fiberglass water-heater blanket to replace oven insulation ruined by rats

Tags: insulation, oven

Is there any reason to NOT use this type of insulating material to wrap a kitchen oven?  It was all I could find in a hurry and seems like it should be adequate to handle the temperatures outside the oven.  The metal sides of the stove barely get warm and cooking seems to be OK.  However, my daughter commented that when using the oven she can smell an odor that gives her a headache.  Is there a reason she might smell this that I am missing?  We are still trying go find the exact fit parts from LG.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Are you **replacing** or **supplementing** the insulation? If the former, then I'd be concerned about handling the temperatures.

Comment: I have read that some new ovens have this same problem and it takes a few cycles for the material to out gas. I would open a window or turn on the exhaust fan and run the oven to a high temp and see if that cures the off gassing issue.